# Distribution of non-trivial zeros of the Riemann ζ‑function

Tags: probability-distributions, roots, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

This question is about statistical properties of the distribution of the complex part of [non-trivial zeros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Zeros,_the_critical_line,_and_the_Riemann_hypothesis) $\rho_n$ of the Riemann $\zeta$‑function. The zeros tend to become more dense as $n$ grows, but we can compensate for that if we consider $\tau_n=\theta\left(\Im\,\rho_n\right)/\pi$ instead, were $\theta(x)$ is the [Riemann–Siegel *θ*‑function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_theta_function). These values appear to lie close to the straight line: $\tau_n\approx n-3/2$, <s>where the absolute error apparently does not exceed 1.</s> *Update:* I've found slightly larger deviations among $2\cdot10^5<n<3\cdot10^5$.
[image: plot]

Is this known to be true (at least, if we assume the Riemann hypothesis)?

If we consider $\tau_n-\left(n-3/2\right)$ as a random variable, can we determine its standard deviation and other statistical properties?

Do we know what distribution does it follow? It looks close to normal.

[image: distribution]

Comment: This is not a question of SE but a question of MO

Comment: [Probably relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery%27s_pair_correlation_conjecture)

Comment: @Vladimir Reshetnikov , what is the  probablity of these non trivial  zeros to lie in your straight line according this distribution you have got  ?

Comment: I haven't seen any $\tau_n$ to lie exactly on the straight line $n-3/2$, but their deviations from that line correspond to $x$-coordinate of the gray vertical lines on my last plot, and the blue curve is an estimated PDF of their distribution. The sample of $10^5$ first values shows the standard deviation $\approx 0.29$, median absolute deviation $\approx 0.20$ and kurtosis $\approx 2.65$. The largest absolute deviation in that sample is $\approx 0.948471 < 1$. A normal distribution has kurtosis $=3$.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov , The best way to know  your distribution what is it just to use normality test since you have data looking to the p-value

Comment: Indexes of positive terms among $\tau_n-\left(n-3/2\right)$ seems to match the sequence https://oeis.org/A282896. It might be not _exactly_ that sequence, though, because its definition uses only an approximation to the inverse of $\theta(x)$ in terms of Lambert $W$-function.